# Implementing Flutter Icons in the `buildMenuItem()` Widget

Tags: flutter

In the Container widget, I have tried implementing many flutter icons and all are working well except for the `cell_tower_rounded`. This is an icon that is as well supported by [icons Null safety](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/cell_tower_rounded-constant.html).Kindly help why is this cell_tower icon not working while the rest are just ok.
My editor underlines it in red and the error is `undefined_getter`

```
Container(padding,child,childred[
buildMenuItem(
    text: 'Connection Status',
    icon: Icons.cell_tower_rounded,
    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 0),
]),
```

[image]

Comment: why is child,childred?

Comment: Value for icon should be 
icon: Icon(Icons.yourIcon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your contributions, But well, I figured it out and found a fix. The problem was that my `Flutter Version` was out of date. Most of the latest icons are not easily supported in previous flutter versions.
I was using `Flutter: 2.8.2` while at the time of release of `cell_tower_rounded` icon, flutter version was at `Flutter: 2.10.2`.
Incase you are experiencing a unique problem with some widgets, packages or icons, simple run: `$ flutter upgrade` in your project directory.

You'll probably also need to update your Kotlin Version in the `android/build.gradle` to the latest one.Find the latest Kotlin version [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html):
Today(as at the time of this post), the latest one is version 1.6.0, so kindly update like this:

```dart
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Comment: is this problem mention in githhub

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some typo on your code. The correct should be

```
Container(padding,child:Row(children[
buildMenuItem(
    text: 'Connection Status',
    icon: Icon(Icons.cell_tower_rounded),
    onClicked: () => selectedItem(context, 0),
])),
```

You can use either `Row` or `Column`. It depends on what you want.

Comment: this icondata missing `cell_tower_rounded`.coud'nt access .missing from sdk .i coudn't find this variable in flutter sdk as mentioned in document.is it bug or .i think you coud